# Autoload error: Vendor autoload is not found. Please run 'composer install' under application root directory in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, installation, composer, git

I've cloned a gitlab project into the local system in Windows. When I run the project, it shows this error:

```
Vendor autoload is not found. 
Please run 'composer install' under the application root directory.
```

Please tell what are the things to be done.
And also why do the files like `env.php` are missing in `app/etc` folders when cloning it from gitlab?

Comment: + for answer acceptance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually your vendor is empty, because it always added in `.gitignore`. To resolve this follow these steps

1. Download and install [composer for windows](https://getcomposer.org/download/)
2. Run CMD and go to your project directory
3. Run composer install. This will install all the required modules in vendor directory
4. Now execute following commands and check after that

`php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer --skip-compilation
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush`

This should resolve your issue

Comment: Excellent. It worked very well. But admin page showing blank now after setup install. Can you tell how to solve that?

Comment: turn on php error reporting, and check if your mode is development. Also check `var/log/exception.log`. By this you can get actual error

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much