# temando module-shipping-m2 error

Tags: shipping, magento2.2.6, setup-di-compile, temando

Disable the temando module-shipping-m2 then i got error
magento 2.2.6

```
-bash-4.2$ /opt/plesk/php/7.1/bin/php bin/magento setup:di:compile
    Compilation was started.
    Proxies code generation... 0/7 [>-------------]  14% < 1 sec 62.0 MiBPHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Temando\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Packaging\Collection::fetchData() must be compatible with Temando\Shipping\Model\ResourceModel\Webservice\Collection::fetchData(Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $criteria) in /var/www/html/####/httpdocs/###/vendor/temando/module-shipping-m2/Model/ResourceModel/Packaging/Collection.php on line 21
    -bash-4.2$
```

in /var/www/html/####/httpdocs/###/vendor/temando/module-shipping-m2/Model/ResourceModel/Packaging/Collection.php on line 21

Comment: try to change the php version

Comment: my php version is 7.1.33

Answer (score 0):

try to following way..

```
rm -rf vendor/* <br>
composer update
```

Comment: i try this, i have "Vendor autoload is not found. Please run 'composer install' under application root directory." error

Comment: @KGR check here answer :https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/285017/68695